# make resource apply to both classes XTerm and UXTerm

Tags: x11, xterm, x-resources

In order to apply the same resource to both `xterm` and `uxterm`, currently my configuration file has to have separate, duplicate entries:

```
XTerm*scrollBar:           true
UXTerm*scrollBar:          true
```

Wildcarding the class name, for instance, will not pick up both of them:

```
! This works for xterm but not uxterm
*XTerm*scrollBar:          true
```

Is there a way to make certain resources apply to both programs (which are really the same program underneath anyway), while retaining the ability to have other resources apply specifically to one or the other (which rules out, say, always starting `xterm` via `xterm -class UXTerm`)?  Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have multiple XTerm configurations and choose one at invocation time, you can use a single class and multiple instance names:

```
XTerm.VT100.background: Black
XTerm.VT100.scrollBar: true
light.VT100.background: White
```

With these definitions, `xterm -name light` has a white background and has scroll bars. You can get two tiers of configuration this way, but if you want three tiers, this won't help.

In this specific case, you could perhaps use

```
?.VT100.background: Black
Light.VT100.background: White
```

because in practice, xterm is the only application with a `VT100` widget.

In general, you can't do this with the basic X resource syntax alone. Wildcards match components, not individual characters inside components. `*XTerm` means “`XTerm` at any level of the hierarchy”, not “any name that ends with `XTerm`”.

The solution is to rely on the **preprocessor**. `xrdb` (the utility that loads X resources) uses the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (`cpp`) by default. Unfortunately, cpp is not very convenient for the X resource syntax. In particular, you can't have a line break in the expansion of a cpp macro, so you can't define a macro to expand to multiple X resources. However, you can solve your problem with cpp using include files. Put the common definitions for `XTerm` and `UXTerm` in a separate file `xterm-common.Xresources`. In your main `.Xresources` file, include `xterm-common.Xresources` twice, once for each class name.

```
#include ".config/x11/xterm-common-Xresources"
#define XTerm UXTerm
#include ".config/x11/xterm-common-Xresources"
#undef XTerm
XTerm.font: my XTerm font
UXTerm.font: my UXTerm font
```

I use [m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)) to preprocess my X resources. This means that I can't rely on the default loading of `~/.Xresources`: I call `xrdb -cpp m4 ~/path/to/my/Xresources` explicitly from my `.xinitrc` or `.xsession`. I have code to apply some resources for both `XTerm` and `UXTerm`:

```
define(`XTERM_class_settings', `
  …

') dnl end of `XTERM_class_settings'

XTERM_class_settings
define(`XTerm', `UXTerm')
XTERM_class_settings
undefine(`XTerm')
```

Comment: I love the preprocessor trick! I only wish it worked. :-/ My result: (a) resources set in `xterm-common` file applied to `xterm`; (b) resources set in `.Xdefaults` applied to `xterm` or `uxterm` as appropriate; (c) resources set in `xterm-common` file _not_ applied to `uxterm`.  The first `#include` is clearly working, per (a).  Not sure how to debug whether the `#define` or the second `#include` is failing.

Comment: @Targeloid Start by running `cpp ~/.Xdefaults | less` and reviewing the output. Also, if resources aren't having effect, review the output of `xrdb -query` to check whether the problem is that they aren't set as desired or that they don't have the desired effect. If `xrdb -query` looks right, check with `appres` to see what resources are applied to a particular class and optionally instance. `xrdb -query` only includes user-defined resources, `appres` also takes system defaults into account.

Comment: Curiously, running `cpp ~/.Xdefaults > cpp_out; mv ~/.Xdefaults ~/.save.Xdefaults; mv cpp_out ~/.Xdefaults` makes both `xterm` and `uxterm` work.  But with the original `~/.Xdefaults` in place, only bare `xterm` does.  So the syntax is correct, but the X toolkit's automated system seems to be mishandling the `#define` or the second `#include`.  (Using an `~/.Xdefaults` file does not load the resources into the server, but reads them upon startup of each X application, so `xrdb -query -all` returns nothing.)

Comment: @Targeloid Oh, I think the per-application reading of `.Xdefaults` doesn't use the preprocessor. It's something the `xrdb` tool does.

Comment: That's what I suspected at first, but it must be doing the first `#include`, or point (a) above wouldn't be true.

Comment: @Targeloid `#include` is built into the X resource syntax. It's only a coincidence that this is compatible with the cpp syntax. (Historically it isn't a coincidence, the Xresources `#include` syntax was copied from cpp, but technically these are independent.)

Comment: Huh, a bizarre design choice to re-implement functionality that could be easily (and more flexibly) attained merely by calling cpp, where it's already implemented.  But it does explain the results.  Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcarding doesn't work in X resources as you might use *glob* expressions in a shell.  It's more like an ellipsis "...", replacing zero or more levels of the widget hierarchy.

If you eliminate the class name, using just `*scrollBar:true`, that would apply to both xterm and uxterm (as well as any other application using that resource name).